# com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure for remote client

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have written code for quiz application in Java. However, the problem is that the code is running fine on local PC (with jar file), but when I created the .jar file, and run on other client machine (In Local Connection), the following error shown:

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:151)

Here is the code for database:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Database {
    static String q[][]=new String[21][7];
    static String teamID;
    static String answers[][]=new String[21][2];
    static String user;
    //static String connString="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demoquiz";
    static String connString="jdbc:mysql://192.168.150.105:3306/demoquiz";
    static String dbuser="root";
    static String pass="";
    int marks=0;
    public Database()throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            
    }
    
    public boolean loginCheck(String a,String b) throws Exception {
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connString,dbuser,pass);
        String query="select * from reginfo where U_NAME=? and U_PASS=?";
        
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, a);
        ps.setString(2, b);     
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome user", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            user=rs.getString(1);
            
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            con.close();        
            return true;    
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or Password Incorrect!!\n Try Again", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            con.close();
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    public void register (String a,String b,String c,String d,String e)throws Exception {
        
            
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connString,dbuser,pass);
            String query="insert into reginfo(U_NAME,T_ID,U_PASS,U_CLG,U_BID) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
            
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);   
            ps.setString(1, a);
            ps.setString(2, b);
            ps.setString(3, c);
            ps.setString(4, d);
            ps.setString(5, e);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration Successful", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: You can ping `192.168.150.105` from the client machine?  MySQL is installed and is running on `192.168.150.105` and allows remote connections?

Comment: I have checked the ping and also MYSQL is running on server machine. Can you please help me with allowing remote connections.